# I can't change language in DatePicker - Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} locale={plLocale}>
          <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 30 }}>
            <DatePicker
              label="Data początkowa"
              value={date[0]}
              format='dd-MM-yyyy'
              disabled={!selectedOption}
              onChange={(newValue) => {
                setDate([newValue, date[1]]);
              }}
              renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} />}            />
            <span style={{ margin: '0 8px' }}>-</span>
            <DatePicker
              label="Data końcowa"
              value={date[1]}
              format='dd-MM-yyyy'
              disabled={!selectedOption}
              onChange={(newValue) => {
                setDate([date[0], newValue]);
              }}
              renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} />}            />
          </div>
        </LocalizationProvider>
```

My imports:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import './Menu.css';
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';
import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import Switch from '@mui/material/Switch';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import moment from 'moment';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import axios from 'axios';
import CircularProgress from '@mui/material/CircularProgress';
import Radio from '@mui/material/Radio';
import RadioGroup from '@mui/material/RadioGroup';
import FormLabel from '@mui/material/FormLabel';
import { pl } from 'date-fns/locale';
import plLocale from 'date-fns/locale/pl';
```

I've tried everything e. g. moving the LocalizationProvider component to a higher level in my components tree (index.js), I've updated every package. I've tried some methods with another date packages. I have no idea why it is not working. I need your help.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `adapterLocale` instead of `locale` in your

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} locale={plLocale}>
```

Refer [Material UI Doc](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/adapters-locale/) for further information